# Google Script Code to send email and hide row

Tags: google-sheets

I have code that I want to use to send an email and hide a row if the value of the edited cell is "V" or "v" and the user confirms that a person voted (as denoted by the "V" or "v").  I am running into the following issues:

1. The email is not sending (note:  I have defined the onEdit function as a trigger for change and edit, so I have installed it manually.)
2. The row is not hiding automatically.
3. The alert box seems to fire twice.

Here is my code:

```
     function onEdit(event){

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var r=event.range
     var c=r.getA1Notation();

     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var response = ui.prompt('Did This Voter Vote?', r.offset(0,-1,1).getValue(), ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

     var sb=response.getSelectedButton();

    var v=r.getValue();

    if ((v=="v" || v=="V" ) && sb == ui.Button.YES) {


    var N=r.offset(0,-2,1).getValue();
    var nme=r.offset(0,-1,1).getValue();


    MailApp.sendEmail('address@email.com', "Voter #" + N,"David, this is to tell you that "+ nme+ " just voted.");
    sheet.hideRow(r.row());

    } else {

    r.setValue("");


      }
     }
```

Any assistance would be great!  Thank you!

Comment: not well versed with hideRow.
But after reading [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRow(Range))
Perhaps instead of
`sheet.hideRow(r.row());`

This might work instead?
`sheet.hideRow(r);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a fiddle with your original code, some bits in there, you really don't need. All a bit confusing,

I got everything working except emailing, and I think that's because you cannot email on an onEdit event. It doesn't have the right authorization.

A work around is to push your "email" data to a sheet. 
Then use a simple script to send the emails to you, perhaps on a timer.

```
function onEdit(event){

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var r=event.source.getActiveRange();
     var c=r.getA1Notation();

     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var response = ui.prompt('Did This Voter Vote?', r.offset(0,-1,1).getValue(), ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      Logger.log(response);
     var sb=response.getSelectedButton();

    var value=r.getValue();

    if ((value=="v" || value=="V" ) && sb == ui.Button.YES) {


    var N=r.offset(0,-2,1).getValue();
    var nme=r.offset(0,-1,1).getValue();

    sheet.hideRow(r);
//    MailApp.sendEmail('address@email.com', "Voter #" + N,"David, this is to tell you that "+ nme+ " just voted.");


    } else {

    r.setValue("");


      }
     }
```